# java conditional how do I make sure it checks all if statements

Tags: java

I am having trouble getting the below query method to work. I need it to return if `isRestricted` all of the reports with restricted in the status. If isClosed then return all reports that are closed for the status. It works for `isRestricted`, returns all reports in restricted status. It also works for returning everything except restricted and closed which is good, but just returns everything for the if `isClosed` condition. Now if I move the `isClosed` conditions to the top then it works for isClosed, but doesn't work for `isRestricted`. What am I missing?

```
 protected String getRestrictedOrClosedTerm() {
    if (isRestricted == null || "false".equals(isRestricted)) {
        return "-status:restricted  -status:closed ";
    }
    if (isRestricted.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    if ("true".equals(isRestricted)) {
       return "+status:restricted ";
    }
    if (isClosed == null || "false".equals(isClosed)) {
        return "-status:closed ";
    }
    if (isClosed.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    if ("true".equals(isClosed)) {
        return "+status:closed ";
    }

    return "";
}
```

It is like it is stopping at the:

```
 if ("true".equals(isRestricted)) {
       return "+status:restricted ";
    }
```

Interestingly if I use this I get the desired results, but not sure why:

```
  protected String getRestrictedOrClosedTerm() {
     if ("true".equals(isClosed)) {
         return "+status:closed ";
     }
     if ("true".equals(isRestricted)) {
         return "+status:restricted ";
     }
     if (isRestricted == null || "false".equals(isRestricted)) {
        return "-status:restricted  -status:closed ";
     }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` and append whatever is relevant, and return its `.toString()`

Comment: Can you give me an example? Sorry I have never used a StringBuilder. Java newb here.

Comment: `return` ends the function. So it's only possible for 1 of your ifs to be executed

Comment: @fge +1 to you. Using StringBuilder to construct a return value is an important, standard approach to a variety of problems.

Comment: I am playing with a StringBuilder now... I can see the value.

Comment: When you return from the middle of an `if` statement, nothing else happens in the method (except for some odd cases with try/finally).  Rather than returning, you need to set flags/variables/logs that you can check later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a `return` in a method, it exits that method with the value returned. If you use something like a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), you can see all the output:

```
        protected String getRestrictedOrClosedTerm() 
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (isRestricted == null || "false".equals(isRestricted)) {
                sb.append("-status:restricted  -status:closed\n");
            }
            if (isRestricted.isEmpty()) {
                sb.append("empty\n");
            }
            if ("true".equals(isRestricted)) {
                sb.append("+status:restricted\n");
            }
            if (isClosed == null || "false".equals(isClosed)) {
                sb.append("-status:closed\n");
            }
            if (isClosed.isEmpty()) {
                sb.append("empty\n");
            }
            if ("true".equals(isClosed)) {
                sb.append("+status:closed\n");
            }

            return sb.toString();
        }
```